# remove {} from Tkinter label

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi

```
import Tkinter
window=Tk()
msg1='abc'
msg2='def'
label =Label(window,text=(msg1,msg2), fg='blue')
label.grid(row=0,column=1)
window.mainloop()
```

output is `{abc}{def}`  I want output as `abcdef`. how to do that?

Comment: have you tried `text=msg1+msg2`?

Comment: When I test your code, it displays `abc def`
(after changing `import Tkinter` to `from Tkinter import *`)

Comment: yes that's the solution. thank you very much @Morb

Comment: I wrote it as an answer so you can setthe question as answered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're writing `text=(msg1,msg2)` with `(msg1,msg2)` being a list.
Just change it to `msg1+msg2`

And this code cannot work, you can't create a `Tk()` if you import Tkinter like that.
Change it to `from Tkinter import *`